# How to change grub defaults?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, grub, defaults

I've got Ubuntu 10.04 and Grub 0.97, I've created `/etc/default/grub` (according to example in menu.lst):

```
defoptions=
howmany=all
```

But every-time when `update-grub` is executed `quite splash` is appended as kernel parameter. I cannot find out why this happens even if created default file and the file is

```
title           Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS, kernel 2.6.32-28-generic-pae
uuid            c90f570d-b8a0-4c2e-a285-47905d46d3ce
kernel          /vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic-pae root=/dev/mapper/vg0-lvRoot ro quiet splash
initrd          /initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic-pae
```

```
located during `update-grub`, as you can see:
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic-pae
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
```

I also tried edit menu.lst "defaults", but `update-grub` doesn't take care about them.
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As I remember you should change some line in the `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file.

You can find there some **commented** lines:

```
# defoptions=
# howmany=all
```

These line should be **commented** and you can define these parameter. The `update-grup` script analyzes these parameters and builds proper `menu.list` file.

Comment: I did that, but when `update-grub` is executed, these config directives are in part which is generated by `update-grub` and it is override.

Comment: Are you sure that you make changes in the `/boot/grub/menu.lst`? In the question you write that you changed `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: "I also tried edit menu.lst "defaults", but update-grub doesn't take care about them."

Comment: Sorry I miss it. And unfortunately I cannot help you more.